# Spinner probability when not pointing at C

Tags: probability

A spinner is mounted on a wheel of unit circumference. Arcs A, B, and C of
lengths 1/3, 1/2, and 1/6, respectively, are marked on the wheel's perimeter. The spinner
is flicked and we know that it is not pointing toward C. What is the probability that it points toward A?

Thank you!

Comment: Does "Conditional Probability" ring any bell?

Answer (score 0):

The [conditional probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) is
$$
P(A\mid\lnot C)=\frac{P(A\cap\lnot C)}{P(\lnot C)}=\frac{P(A)}{P(A)+P(B)}
$$